# Fabric UI Core Grid Layout DOES NOT WORK

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I have a very simple HTML page that in summary includes the Fabric UI CSS file and has a body (body.ms-Fabric) with

```
<div class="ms-Grid">
    <div class="ms-Grid-row">
        <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-sm12 ms-u-md4 ms-lg2">
            Column 1
        </div>
        <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-sm12 ms-md8 ms-lg10">
            Column 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but is displaying two rows instead of the expected two columns

What am I doing wrong?

Am I missing any other CSS include or class?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It does work. :)
They seem to have forgotten to update their guide when they included rtl support. **Simply add dir="ltr"** to the html tag or at least the div parent to .ms-Grid-col

```html
<link href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.3.0/css/fabric.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ms-Fabric" dir="ltr">

  <div class="ms-Grid">
    <div class="ms-Grid-row">
      <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-sm6 ms-md4 ms-lg2">A</div>
      <div class="ms-Grid-col ms-sm6 ms-md8 ms-lg10">B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue here, I dont know why we are missing float left:

```
.ms-Grid-col{
 position:relative;
 min-height:1px;
 padding-left:8px;
 padding-right:8px;
 box-sizing:border-box}

[dir=ltr] .ms-Grid-col{float:left}
[dir=rtl] .ms-Grid-col{float:right}
```

if you add `float:left;` to `.ms-grid-col` class then it will be ok

Comment: Yup, that fixed it... however I am now very concerned about the reliability of UI Fabric. If such simple issue has not been caught as part of the testing Microsoft should have done, what else I will encounter moving forward?!

Comment: I had this issue when using fabric in a dialog (pop-up) the direction attribute was only available in the page not in the (iframe: popup). That can maybe explain the bug
Did you use it the same way ?